# Simplifying $2^{\sqrt {2\lg t}}$

Tags: logarithms

Simplifying $2^{\sqrt {2\lg t}}$ should yield $t^{\sqrt {2/\lg t}}$, but the following is what I am getting:

$$\begin{align}
y &= 2^{\sqrt {2\lg t}}\\
y &= 2^{\sqrt {\lg t{^2}}}\\
y &= 2^{({{\lg t{^2}})}^{1/2}}\\
\lg y &= \lg{2^{({{\lg t{^2}})}^{1/2}}}\\
\lg y &= (\lg t{^2})^{1/2} \cdot \lg 2\\
\lg y &= (\lg t{^2})^{1/2}
\end{align}$$

and then I'm not sure if I am heading towards a correct solution or not because after the last step I'm really confused. I'm not sure how I could get $y =t^{\sqrt {2/\lg t}}$.

Comment: I can see a transformation, but I don't see much of a simplification.

Comment: @sss Please, don't delete your question once you get an answer -- one of the the goals of this website is to keep these questions and answers archived, so that they may benefit other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to *start from the other end:*

For $t>1$,
$$
t^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}}
= 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}\lg t}
= 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}\sqrt{ (\lg t)^2}}
= 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}\cdot (\lg t)^2}}
= 2^{\sqrt{ 2 \lg t}}
$$
where we first used (1) that $a^b = 2^{b\lg a}$ for any $a>0$ and $b$, and (2) then $\lg t >0$ (as $t>1$) to say that $\lg t = \sqrt{(\lg t)^2}$.

Comment: is there any way to go the other way :) ? @ClementC

Comment: @ssss Sure, do the steps in the other direction.
$$2^{\sqrt{ 2 \lg t}} = 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}\cdot (\lg t)^2}} = 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}\cdot (\lg t)^2}} = 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}\sqrt{ (\lg t)^2}} = 2^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}\lg t} = t^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}}$$
But it's (a bit) harder to figure out the steps in that direction, which is why I suggested to start the other way around.

Comment: sorry if I'm being pedantic, but is "$\lg$" a common abbreviation? - never seen it used before

Comment: @mrnovice [It is often/sometimes used for $\log_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Notation).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for that it makes sense now

Comment: @ClementC. thanks but $2^{\sqrt{{{(2/lgt}) * (lgt)^2}}}$ is confusing and not sure how you got it

Comment: @ssss You have $2\lg t = \frac{2(\lg t)^2}{\lg t}$, and thus  $\sqrt{2\lg t} = \sqrt{\frac{2(\lg t)^2}{\lg t}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}\sqrt{(\lg t)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\lg t}}\lg t$.  (We used $\lg t >0$ in the last step to write $\sqrt{(\lg t)^2}=\lg t$.)